# EventListener for generic Events with Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, event-listener

I have two beans of the same class that I want to listen each for a bean-specific but generic event:

```
public class MyBeanClass <E> {
  @EventListener
  public void handleEvent(E event) { ... }
}
```

Config:

```
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  public MyBeanClass<AEvent> myBeanAClass() {
    return new MyBeanClass<>();
  }
  @Bean
  public MyBeanClass<BEvent> myBeanBClass() {
    return new MyBeanClass<>();
  }
}
```

So bean "myBeanAClass" shall listen for AEvent's and bean "myBeanBClass" shall listen for BEvent's.

Test:

```
@Test
 public void testHandleAEvent() {
   AEvent event = new AEvent();
   publisher.publishEvent(event);
   Mockito.verify(myBeanAClass, times(1)).handleEvent(Mockito.any()); // Fail
   Mockito.verify(myBeanBClass, times(0)).handleEvent(Mockito.any());
 }
```

Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
mypackage.MyBeanClass#0 bean.handleEvent(
    <any>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at mypackage.MyTest.testHandleAEvent(MyTest.java:45)
But was 5 times:
-> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
-> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
-> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
-> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
-> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the generic type `E` in `handleEvent(E event)` will be replaced with `Object`. After replacement class will look:

```java
public class MyBeanClass {
  @EventListener
  public void handleEvent(Object event) { ... }
}
```

It means that such listener will accept any events from the application even generated by the spring framework internally. The method signature declares the event type it consumes. [EventListener documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html)

**Solution 1. Create listener adapter foreach event**

Adapters for base generic listener:

```java
public class MyBeanClass <E> {
    public void handleEvent(E event) {
        event.toString();
    }
}

public class MyBeanAClass {
    private MyBeanClass<AEvent> myBeanClass;

    public MyBeanAClass(MyBeanClass<AEvent> myBeanClass) {
        this.myBeanClass = myBeanClass;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleEvent(AEvent event) {
        myBeanClass.handleEvent(event);
    }
}

public class MyBeanBClass {
    private MyBeanClass<BEvent> myBeanClass;

    public MyBeanBClass(MyBeanClass<BEvent> myBeanClass) {
        this.myBeanClass = myBeanClass;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleEvent(BEvent event) {
        myBeanClass.handleEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Events:

```java
public class AEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private final String message;

    public AEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class BEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private final String message;

    public BEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Config:

```java
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBeanAClass myBeanAClass() {
        return new MyBeanAClass(new MyBeanClass<>());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBeanBClass myBeanBClass() {
        return new MyBeanBClass(new MyBeanClass<>());
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
class ApplicationTests {
    @MockBean
    private MyBeanAClass myBeanAClass;

    @MockBean
    private MyBeanBClass myBeanBClass;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Test
    public void testHandleAEvent() {
        AEvent event = new AEvent(this, "Message");
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
        Mockito.verify(myBeanAClass, times(1)).handleEvent(Mockito.any());
        Mockito.verify(myBeanBClass, times(0)).handleEvent(Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

**Solution 2. Generic Application Event**
Create a generic event type. Implement `org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider` in generic event class, then listener will resolve it.

```java
public class GenericSpringEvent<T> implements ResolvableTypeProvider {
    private final T source;

    public GenericSpringEvent(T source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public T getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public ResolvableType getResolvableType() {
        return ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(
                getClass(),
                ResolvableType.forInstance(this.source)
        );
    }
}
```

Implement generic listeners for each event

```java
public class GenericSpringAEventListener {
    @EventListener
    public void handle(GenericSpringEvent<AEvent> event) {
        event.toString();
    }
}

public class GenericSpringBEventListener {
    @EventListener
    public void handle(GenericSpringEvent<BEvent> event) {
        event.toString();
    }
}
```

Config:

```java
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public GenericSpringAEventListener genericSpringAEventListener() {
        return new GenericSpringAEventListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public GenericSpringBEventListener genericSpringBEventListener() {
        return new GenericSpringBEventListener();
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
class ApplicationTests {
    @MockBean
    private GenericSpringAEventListener aListener;

    @MockBean
    private GenericSpringBEventListener bListener;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Test
    public void testHandleAEvent() {
        AEvent event = new AEvent(this, "Message");
        GenericSpringEvent<AEvent> genericEvent = new GenericSpringEvent<>(event);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(genericEvent);
        Mockito.verify(aListener, times(1)).handle(Mockito.any());
        Mockito.verify(bListener, times(0)).handle(Mockito.any());
    }
}
```