# Spring EventListener can't catch event when parameter is List<MyType>

Tags: spring-boot, event-listener

It is my event publisher.

```
public void evnetMaker(){
  List<MyType> messages = ...;
  System.out.println("Event publish");
  applicationEventPublisher.publishEvnet(messages);
  System.out.println("End Event");
}
```

It is eventListener.

```
@EventListener
public void listenEvent(List<MyType> messages){
  System.out.println("Listen");
}
```

I expect

```
Event publish
Listen
End Event
```

But actual

```
Event publish
End Event
```

I think evnet listener can't handle List<>.

So I fixed it like this.

```
public void evnetMaker(){
  List<MyType> messages = ...;
  ...
  applicationEventPublisher.publishEvnet(new CustomEvent(messages));
  ...
}
```

and

```
@EventListener
public void listenEvent(CustomEvent customEvent){
  ...
  customEvent.getMessages();
  ...
}
```

It works well.

I wonder that why spring @EventListener doesn't work when parameter is List<>.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a problem with the `List<>` implementation. The Problem exists for every event that uses generic types.
As explained in [another Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453722/13670629) the problem resides in the way java handles generics. Because of type erasure, the generics will be replaced with `Object` types. Because of this, it is not possible to distinguish between different events just by the generic type.
What you can do, as described in the post linked above, is to implement your own `List` class that also implements the `ResolvableTypeProvider`. It could look something like this:

```
class MyList<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements ResolvableTypeProvider {
    @Override
    public ResolvableType getResolvableType() {
        return ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(
                getClass(),
                ResolvableType.forInstance(getFirst()));
    }

}
```

Note: This example doesn't work for empty instances of `MyList` as there is no first element for the `getFirst()` method to return.

Your example with the `CustomEvent` as a wrapper for the list does work, because the event listener does not need to resolve a generic but can simply look for listeners of the `CustomEvent` type.

For more information please have a look at the mentioned post or in the documentation for [ResolvableType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html) as well as a [blogpost](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) by Spring.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works:

```
@EventListener(List.class)
public void listenEvent(List<MyType> messages){
  System.out.println("Listen");
}
```

But we lose type narrowing